# PowerShell Test-Path -exclude

Tags: powershell

I need to perform a check on a target folder, and check if the file is from today and has more than 5kb

The below command provide a bool value based on the existence of the file using the today date, but I would like to add also an exclusion like -gt5kb

I tried to use -Exlcude but I'm not sure on how it work.

```
$integration = Test-Path  'C:\Users\EA\Desktop\CATS HTML*' -NewerThan (Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Do you have any advice on how can I include also the size check in the same statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the `Test-Path` cmdlet.

The exclude parameter is defined as follow:

> Specifies items that this cmdlet omits. The value of this parameter
>   qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as
>   "*.txt". Wildcard characters are permitted.

You will need a second method to perform the check. Here an example using the `Get-Item` cmdlet:

```
if (Get-Item 'yourfile.html'| Where-Object Length -gt 5kb) {
      # do something
}
```